# Can I use external video player in SharePoint 2013 display template?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

Can I use external video player (rather than silverlight and html5 players) within the display template?

When i hover on some specific videos in search results it should play in my video player. I am using my custom video hover template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No sure but you can try to add HTML and JavaScript code (of custom video player) in display template and upload it again or create new display template and use the new one.
Hope this will help.